# How to run query on array of objects in parse

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I have a table of USER_LOCATION on parse of user locations. I am saving current location in a separate column and keeping it previous locations in a separate column. Current Location column is of GeoPoints type while previous locations column is of type array. Objects placed in previous locations is like:

```
[
{"location":{"__type":"GeoPoint","latitude":12.3456789,"longitude":12.3456789},"time":"Fri, 22 Jan 2016 11:10:14 GMT"},
{"location":{"__type":"GeoPoint","latitude":12.3456789,"longitude":12.3456789},"time":"Thu, 21 Jan 2016 11:10:14 GMT"},
{"location":{"__type":"GeoPoint","latitude":12.3456789,"longitude":12.3456789},"time":"Wed, 20 Jan 2016 11:10:14 GMT"},
{"location":{"__type":"GeoPoint","latitude":12.3456789,"longitude":12.3456789},"time":"Sat, 23 Jan 2016 11:10:14 GMT"}
]
```

Now I want to show data that where was the selected user on a selected time. E.g. If user has selected user A and selected date 23 jan then I have to show that user A was at "latitude":12.3456789,"longitude":12.3456789 on 23rd Jan. How can I query that?

One option which is so costly w.r.t time is that I fetch all objects of table which have selected user then I loop the array objects and match the time with selected value like:

```
var matQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.Object.extend("UserLocations"));
    matQuery.containedIn("user_id",request.param.userIds);
    matQuery.find({
        success: function(matchArray){
            for(var i=0;i<matchArray.length;i++){
               var prevLocArray = matchArray[i].get("PREV_LOCATION");
               for(var j=0;<prevLocArray.length;j++){
                   var obj = prevLocArray[j];
                   //match obj.time with provided time
               }
            }
        },error: function(err){
            response.success(err.message);
        }
    });
```

Can anyone guide me how can I do it using query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the question asks: "If my _User has an array of locations/times, how do I find the location for a set of users at a particular time?"

The posted code is about as far as you'll get given the data structure.  `Parse.Query` cannot query into the array data except to ask for the presence of an element with an exact match.

Two alternatives are: (a) improve it slightly with a cloud function that does the same work, but doesn't waste the network effort of returning any extra data, or (b) normalize the data by creating a "PrevLocation" class:

```
PrevLocation: "user" (pointer to _User), "date" (Date), "location" (GeoPoint)
```

Query that for user being among a set of users and date satisfying some time window (between the start and end of the target day).  This will run as quick as the platform allows and return only the data you seek.

Remember, you can also `include("user")` on that query to get the complete user objects if you want them.

Comment: That was the last option to apply. I thought may be there is any solution to query inner object like 
    query.lessThan("PREVLOCATION.time",new Date());
Thank you for the answer. Appreciated.